# Background Color remains white regardless of settings

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

I have a "dark background" and "light background" setting on my app. The dark background uses the holo_dark png drawable and works great. However, I'd like the light background to be the grey color used in the g-mail app and other google apps as the background.

In my graphical view of the XML layout the default is a proper gray and looks good. However, in my app the background is white. I've even tried setting it programmatically (not just via XML) and it still appears white!

Strings.xml

```
<color name="grey">#d3d3d3</color>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

MainActivity.java

```
    mBackground.setBackgroundColor(0xd3d3d3);
```

XML View
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9mD6.png

Screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoobZ.png

And before you say the screenshot looks grey, I change the hex code to FF0000 (RED) and it was still white!

I've also removed the background attribute from the layout in the XML file, and wasn't able to change the background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
mBackground.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
```

make new color.xml in values folder like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
        <color name="grey">#d3d3d3</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using

```
mBackground.setBackgroundColor(...);
```

you can pass integer values from the [Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) class, or you can pass hex values **including alpha** (e.g. `0xff000000` for black).

If you want to load your color from XML, first create a `colors.xml` file the `values/` folder as follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
        <color name="grey">#d3d3d3</color>
</resources>
```

and then refer to it using the `background` attribute of your layout, which you already do correctly.

Comment: Is this different from what I'm already doing? You just created a colors.xml to add a value that I just put in my strings.xml. (And this didn't work as shown above.)

Comment: 1. The first part of my post is about setting the color programmatically, which you don't do correctly. 2. Why don't you store your colors in `colors.xml` instead of `strings.xml`? Just do it the way it have to be done and it will work. As simple as that.